# sending periodic emails over django using celery tasks

Tags: django, django-views, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a Group model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
   leader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
   description = models.TextField()
   joined = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
   start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
   end_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
   email_list = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True),
        blank=True,
        default=list,
    )
```

and I want to send an email to all Users who have `joined` a particular Group 30 minutes before the `start_time`. For example: if a Group has a `start_time` of 1:00 PM, I want to send an email to all the `joined` Users at 12:30 PM, letting them know the group will be meeting soon.

I currently have a bunch of celery tasks that run without error, but they are all called within views by the User (creating, updating, joining, leaving, and deleting groups will trigger a celery task to send an email notification to the User).

The scheduled email I am trying to accomplish here will be a periodic task, I assume, and not in the control of the User. However, it isn't like other periodic tasks I've seen because the time it relies on is based on the `start_time` of a specific  Group.

@Brian in the comments pointed out that it can be a regular celery task that is called by the periodic task every minute. Here's my celery task:

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from my_chaburah.settings import NOTIFICATION_EMAIL
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@shared_task(name='start_group_notification_task')
def start_group_notification_task(recipients):
    logger.info('sent email to whole group that group is starting')
    for recipient in recipients:
        send_mail (
                    'group starting',
                    'group starting',
                    NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
                    [recipient],
                    fail_silently=False
                )
```

I'm still not sure exactly how to call this task using a periodic task or how to query my groups and find when groups `start_time` == now + 30mins. I've read the docs, but I'm new to celery and celery beat and a bit confused by how to move forward.

I'm also not sure where exactly to call the task.

my `myapp/celery.py` file:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_group.settings')

app = Celery('my_group')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

my `group/tasks.py` file:

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from my_chaburah.settings import NOTIFICATION_EMAIL
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

I have a bunch of tasks that I didn't include, but I'm assuming any task regarding my Group model would go here. Still not sure though.

I'd also like to add the ability for the leader of the Group to be able to set the amount time prior to `start_time` where the email will be sent. For example: 10, mins, 30 mins, 1hr before meeting, but that's more to do with the model.

Comment: You can add a periodic task that runs every minute, and query your group model on groups that have start times that match the current time + 30 minutes for example.

Comment: Will that overhaul celery?

Comment: Did you mean overload? I guess it depends on your infra and if you do things other than sending emails on the periodic task. If it's just sending emails it should be fine. Also on the periodic task, you can send the email as a celery task

Comment: Yeah, I meant overload. Like, do all apps that send email notification based on a model time do this sort of periodic task? And what do you mean I can send the pt as a celery task

Comment: Yep since the requirement is to send depending on the minute, there should be something that looks out for things to send every minute. You can write a celery task that sends the email, and call that task in your periodic task which runs every minute

Comment: I've edited my question to include my celery task for start time of group, but I'm still struggling to figure out how to check groups using their start time and how/where to set up the periodic task.

Comment: Ok will add an answer. It does not cover things like meetings booked less than 30 mins from now (assuming your reminders are sent 30 mins before), dates handling, and different timezones among other things though but should be enough to get your started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to run the task based on `start_time` but am concerned about issues with runtime.

I added this to my `celery.py` file:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'start_group_notification': {
        'task': 'start_group_notification_task',
        'schedule': crontab(),
    }
}
```

Which runs the task every minute. The task then checks to see if a Group has a start time within 30 minutes. In `group/tasks.py`

```
@shared_task(name='start_group_notification_task')
def start_group_notification_task():
    logger.info('sent email to whole group that group is starting')
    thirty_minutes_from_now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
    groups = Group.objects.filter(
        start_time__hour=thirty_minutes_from_now.hour, 
        start_time__minute=thirty_minutes_from_now.minute
    ).prefetch_related("joined")
    for group in groups:
        for email in group.email_list:
            send_mail (
                    'group starting in 30 minutes',
                    group.name,
                    NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
                    [email],
                    fail_silently=False
                )
```

Now, this works, but I'm concerned about having nested for loops. Is there maybe a better way to do this to have runtime be as little as possible? Or are celery tasks executed fast enough and easy enough that it's not an issue.

As @Brian mentioned this doesn't take into account Users joining within the 30 minute period before a Group starts. The fix to this is for me to see if User joins group within that 30 min period and call a different task to tell them the group is starting soon.

EDIT:
If a User joins a Group within the 30 minute window, I added this variable and conditional:

```
time_left = int(chaburah.start_time.strftime("%H%M")) - int(current_date.strftime("%H%M"))
if  time_left <= 30 and time_left >= 0:
    celery_task.delay()
```

That works if a User joins within the 30, but if the Group has already started I have to implement a new task to let the User know the Group has started.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to configure celery for periodic tasks.

In line with that you can do something roughly similar to this:

```py
import datetime
from celery import Celery
from myapp.models import Group


app = Celery()


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Setup and call send_reminders() every 60 seconds.

    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0, send_reminders, name='check reminders to be sent every minute')


@app.task
def send_reminders():
    # Celery task that gets all groups that needs reminders to be sent 30 minutes from now

    thirty_minutes_from_now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

    groups = Group.objects.filter(
        start_time__hour=thirty_minutes_from_now.hour, 
        start_time__minute=thirty_minutes_from_now.minute
    ).prefetch_related("joined")

    for group in groups:
        for member in group.joined.all():
            send_email_task.delay(member.email)


@app.task
def send_email_task(recipient):
    # Celery task to send emails

    send_mail(
        'group starting',
        'group starting',
        NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
        [recipient],
        fail_silently=False
    )
```

Disclaimer: This is not tested and optimised ;)

Comment: this will theoretically run or it needs to be called somewhere else

Comment: when I ran this code I got this error in my celery terminal `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.` and this code in my regular virtual environment server `django:django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`

Comment: Ok try to change `on_after_configure ` to `on_after_finalize`

Comment: Still getting the error. Let me post my fill `celery.py` file as of now, maybe it's something else in the file that's causing the error.

Comment: Can you also share how you imported celery on the file where the periodic task is

Comment: I'm still not sure which file it should be in. I updated the question to include imports before periodic task which is in the `group/task.py` file vs my `celery.py` which is in the `myapp` directory

Comment: Try importing `app` from `celery.py` instead of using `app = Celery()` in `task.py`

Comment: that's in my `celery.py`. Let me add all the files to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

## Why periodic tasks doesn't work?

There has the bug in Celery <= 5.2.7(stable-version).

It let the periodic tasks doesn't work.

I'm fixed it in this [PR](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/45b5c4a1d4c0c099fc4ccd13fc4c80e2ccedc088), you can edit your Celery source code like this PR, or try the Celery dev-version.

## Soluction 1

```py
# your_app/task.py
@app.on_on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    for group in Group.object.all():
        notification_time = group.start_time - timedelta(minutes=30)
        sender.add_periodic_task(clocked(notification_time),
                                 start_group_notification_task,
                                 kwargs={'recipients':group.recipients}
                                 name='send mail when group start time')
    # You need to connect the `Group.post_save` and `Group.post_delete` signal here,
    # to setup/revoke your periodic tasks when `Group` changed.
```

You can use the [clocked](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/blob/master/django_celery_beat/clockedschedule.py) to be your custom scheduler class, I quoted it from [django-celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat).

## Soluction 2

Maybe you can use the [django-celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat), and create m2m related to your `Group` and `PeriodicTask`.

It looks easier.

---

*Disclaimer: This is not tested and optimised too.*